# How to activate voice dictation on ipad 3?

Tags: ios, ipad, voice-dictation, voice

There is no option like that on the Keyboard option. How can I start it, I thought it was an inbuilt feature and reading other pages they have it. The iOS version is 7.1.2[image]

Comment: I think by "dictation" he's referring to enabling the microphone button in the keyboard so that he can input text by speaking into the microphone... NOT "speak selection", which is having the ipad read text out loud for you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a keyboard feature, it's an accessibility feature.

So go to Settings -> General -> Accessibility

Under vision you will see there is a button called Speak Selection, just press that and turn it on. When you select text you then have an option to let it read for you.

If this doesn't help, let us know, thanks. :)